# Can I use multiple foreign key whose values are coming from same table in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name `permission`. In this table I have two column. Those two column names are `student` and `teacher`. Those two are foreign key. And their reference value coming from `user` table.

What I wanted to do is, If a user id exists is `student` column then this user will be able to do some student related work. And also if a user id exists in `teacher` column then he will be able to do some teacher related work.

So those two column are foreign key. And those two values are coming from `user` table. A user id can exists in both column. So my question is can I use two foreign key whose values are coming from same table?

Or should I create a new column named `user_id` as a foreign key and then if `student` or `teacher` column value is `1` for that user it means that student have permission to do some permitted work.And if the value of `student` or `teacher` column for that user is `0` means that user don't have permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer your second statement to have only one column for the foreign key but two additional columns to distinguish whether it is a student or a teacher or both so there will be no duplicate row for every `user_id`.

```
CREATE TABLE permission 
(
    user_id INT,
    is_student BIT,
    is_teacher BIT,
    -- other columns, if there is any
    INDEX permission_user_id (user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)
)
```

Sample rows:

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| user_id | is_student | is_teacher |
+---------+------------+------------+
| 001     | 1          | 0          |
+---------+------------+------------+
| 002     | 0          | 1          |
+---------+------------+------------+
| 003     | 1          | 1          |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

Or it could be one column for its permission:

```
CREATE TABLE permission 
(
    user_id INT,
    privilege tinyint, -- 1 for student, 2 for teacher, 3 for both
    -- other columns, if there is any
    INDEX permission_user_id (user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id)
)
```

sample rows:

```
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | privilege |
+---------+-----------+
| 001     | 1         |
+---------+-----------+
| 002     | 2         |
+---------+-----------+
| 003     | 3         |
+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: I was suppose to do this, But my confusion is, If I use second method then I have to run `select user_id, student,teacher from permission where `user_id = $user_id` then I have to check if that user have permission or not. On the other side, if I use first method I can do it like this. `select teacher from permission where user_id = $user_id` and then I will check is the user exists on that column or not. I mean if I use first method then I will not have to fetch `user_id` column. I think it will save some speed.

Comment: @Fokrule is it still the same, if you want to check if it is a teacher, for table structure 1 in my answer: `SELECT user_id FROM permission WHERE user_id = $user_id AND is_teacher = 1`. Same with table structure 2, `SELECT user_id FROM permission WHERE user_id = $user_id AND privilege = 2`. If any of the sql above doesn't return any row then it simply means that the user you are searching does not have that functionality.

Comment: I am taking first suggestion.